# iOS badge-only LocalNotification not showing when application in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Edit: I am trying to schedule local notifications that only update the application badge. The notification should not show an alert box or the like.

I am scheduling a local notification when my application starts using the followiing code :

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSDate* scheduled = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate = scheduled;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

NSLog(@"local notif at %@", scheduled);

[application scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Once the application started and before the fireDate, I hit the home button.
My application is put in the background.
In this state, my application does not receive a notification via

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

and the application icon does not decorated with a badge.
Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Edit: Just after posting I tried adding UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to my app Info.plist. My application is terminated as expected when the home button is pressed but the badge still does not appear after the scheduled date. Could this be due to the fact that it is a badge-only local notification ?

Edit: Adding an alert to the notification actually shows the alert. Weird ...

```
localNotif.hasAction = YES;
localNotif.alertAction = @"Hoho";
localNotif.alertBody = @"Hihi";
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code :

```
UILocalNotification* notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; 
notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:seconds]; 
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
localNotif.hasAction = YES;
localNotif.alertAction = @"Hoho";
localNotif.alertBody = @"Hihi";
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber= dayTomorrow;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification]; 
[notification release];
```

Comment: What is dayTomorrow ? Regardless, this will show an alert which I don't want. I only want to update the application badge.

Answer (score 0):

a good tutorial is :

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

and try the example app in this tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, it does not give an answer the actual question. The tutorial shows off notifications using an alert action and body. This works for me. What does not is notification with only a application badge update.